# Is it possible to have Nhibernate prevent a "SQLDateTime overflow"-exception when querying the database?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I'm wondering if it is possible to handle a SQLDateTime-overflow exception in a generel way, so each time I try to query the database for a date prior to 1/1/1753 it won't result in an exception, but instead just convert the out-of-range date to the SQL minimum DateTime.

I only want it to do work when querying the database - NOT when inserting. It makes good sence to trow an exception when trying to insert a wrong date, because that should never happen. But when querying it would be logically right to just convert the time to the minimum time, as this will return zero results.

I imagine something like this, but dont know where to to put it:

```
override DateTime ParseDateTime(DateTime date)
{
   var minDate = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
   if (date < minDate)
     return minDate;
   else
     return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with custom IUserType implementation (sample - http://lostechies.com/rayhouston/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype/)